# PyPng: AttributeError: 'module' object has not attribute 'Writer'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypng

Somewhat new to Python. Trying out PyPNG (need to write some simple PNG files). Using the code (almost) exactly as in the examples in [the documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pypng/ex.html#writing).

```
import png

def main():
  f = open('ramp.png', 'wb')      # binary mode is important
  w = png.Writer(255, 1, greyscale=True)

  w.write(f, [range(256)])

  f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Tried running exactly as written in the documentation (without the main() additions).

When I run, I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Writer'
```

Google and SO offer nothing. Please help?

Comment: After `import png` in your program, add `print(png.__file__)` and edit to include the result.  Probably the module is being shadowed by another program (say, if you called your own program `png.py`.)

Comment: That... is exactly what I did. THANK YOU.